# Android Spinners and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner, android-dialog

I have a `Spinner` that when clicked opens a list of names as a dialog.  I'm wondering if it's possible to add some additional widgets to this dialog.

For example, I'd like to add an `EditText` and `Button` so the user can add a name to the list if they want. Is this possible with the current `Spinner` dialog setup?

If not, my first thought is to subclass `DialogFragment` and have it open when the `Spinner` (or something else in this case) is clicked. Would this be the right direction?

Thanks,
Cohen

Comment: 1. Spinner doesn't have dialog since API 11 - it is popup ... 2. when spinner is showing its list it using normal adapter ... so it acts similar as Listview ... so yes, you can add custom "line" to the listview ... obviously by modifying the Adapter

Comment: I knew you could add custom "lines" or list items, but I'm asking if I can use a custom popup in this case. I suppose it makes sense just to create my own `DialogFragment` and show it myself.

Comment: so you wana show the dialog ? then yes, you have to do it by yourself with DialogFragment or simple AlertDialog (which one can be fed with the same adapter as you can use in Spinner)

Comment: Okay, but what about communicating between the Dialog associated with the Spinner and the Fragment from which the Dialog was shown?  Is it possible to create a Listener for the Spinner's Dialog in the initial Fragment?